# Return jsonb_array_elements result as comma-separated list

Tags: json, postgresql, aggregate-functions, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I am accessing an array (a json object called 'choice_values') in a `jsonb` field, and would like to parse its contents into a comma-separated text field.

```
SELECT
    jsonb_array_elements(doc -> 'form_values' -> '8189' -> 'choice_values')
FROM
    field_data.exports;
```

That jsonb_array_elements function returns a "setof text", which I would like converted to a comma separated list of the array values, contained within a single field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set returning functions (like `jsonb_array_elements_text()`) can be called in SELECT list, but then they cannot be used in aggregate functions.

This is a good practice to call set returning functions in FROM clause, often in a lateral join like in this example:

```
with the_data as (
    select '["alfa", "beta", "gamma"]'::jsonb as js
    )

select string_agg(elem, ',')
from 
    the_data, 
    jsonb_array_elements_text(js) elem;

   string_agg    
-----------------
 alfa,beta,gamma
(1 row)
```

So your query should look like this:

```
select string_agg(elem, ',')
from 
    field_data.exports, 
    jsonb_array_elements_text(doc -> 'form_values' -> '8189' -> 'choice_values') elem;
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`string_agg` aggregate function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) with a sub-select from `jsonb_array_elements_text` seems to work (tested on PG 9.5). Note the use of `jsonb_array_elements_text`, added in PostgreSQL 9.4, rather than `jsonb_array_elements`, from PostgreSQL 9.3.

```
with exports as (
    select $${"form_values": {"8189": {"choice_values": ["a","b","c"]}}}$$::jsonb as doc
)
SELECT
    string_agg(values, ', ')
FROM
    exports, jsonb_array_elements_text(doc -> 'form_values' -> '8189' -> 'choice_values') values
GROUP BY
    exports.doc;
```

Output:

`'a, b, c'`

Also see [this question and its answers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54283/how-to-turn-json-array-into-postgres-array).

Comment: Yes, and I should have noted that in the question, sorry.  For whatever reason, the string_agg function sees the result of jsonb_array_elements() as type "jsonb" rather than "setof text".  Here's the error: "ErrorMessage: function string_agg(jsonb, text) does not exist"

Comment: I overlooked something too in your question. You need to use `jsonb_array_elements_text` ([added in PG 9.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html)) to get `setof text` rather than `jsonb` as the output.

Comment: See the other question I linked to if you have to use PG 9.3 for some reason; it has some workarounds.

Comment: When I replace the jsonb_array_elements() function with jsonb_array_elements_text() I get a new error: "ErrorMessage: set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set"

Comment: After assuming I remember how this worked, twice… I went and tried it and realized that a syntactic change is necessary here. Third time's a charm, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not best practice: convert the json array to text, then remove the brackets.

```
WITH input AS (
    SELECT '["text1","text2","text3"]'::jsonb as data
) 
SELECT substring(data::text,2,length(data::text)-2) FROM input
```

It has the advantage that it converts "in-place", not by aggregating. This could be handy if you can only access part of the query, e.g. for some synchronization tool where there's field-based conversion rules, or something like the following:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE example AS (SELECT '["text1","text2","text3"]'::jsonb as data);
ALTER TABLE example ALTER COLUMN data TYPE text USING substring(data::text,2,length(data::text)-2);
```

Comment: Could you please remove some of the extraneous text from your answer?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/conduct for how to write a concise and factual answer.